# Storing summary statistics for a large table

Tags: database-design, statistics

So I have a large table that stores events triggered by a user. These can be anything from logging on to viewing a profile to messaging another user.

I want to track how many views a user receives.

It's a large table, so I want to avoid doing something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE event_type = 'profile_view' 
AND user_id = ...;
```

I'm trying to think of a good database driven solution that will allow me to store things like profile views in the last 7,14 and even 30 day periods?

Comment: If you have the proper indexes you can run a query like that with minimal I/O on a table with billions of rows.  You are likely trying to over-engineer it, so you need to let us know why you want to avoid doing something like that.  Also, tagging the database produce (slq-server, mysql, or whatever) will help you question get more views.

Comment: What platform (MSSQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL etc) and version? Can you provide the table definition (including current indexes) and some example data and expected output? This is a fairly broad question without too many specifics. Something like SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table GROUP BY Type, User could be a solution but it may be a poor solution - it depends on your schema, data and requirements.